# Jenkins deploying Spring project to Tomcat 8 fails

Tags: jenkins, spring-data, tomcat8

I have configured a Jenkins job that runs the project tests, builds the project and then deploys it to a Tomcat 8 server. This worked perfectly for a short while, untill after a certain commit the deployment started failing. I tried reverting to said commit, without success. I keep getting the error messages below. I have looked this up extensively, but none of the solutions I found worked for me.

A few notes:

- The build works locally (on my pc) and on Jenkins
- The tests pass locally and on Jenkins
- I can successfully deploywhen I go to the Tomcat web application manager and manually deploy the build.war file I compiled locally
- I'm using the "Deploy war/ear to a container" plugin in Jenkins

The error message:

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BuildCharityApplication\complete\pom.xml to org.springframework/gs-rest-service/0.1.0/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BuildCharityApplication\complete\target\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war to org.springframework/gs-rest-service/0.1.0/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war
channel stopped
Deploying C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BuildCharityApplication\complete\target\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context charity
  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BuildCharityApplication\complete\target\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war] is not deployed. Doing a fresh deployment.
  Deploying [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BuildCharityApplication\complete\target\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BuildCharityApplication\complete\target\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path /charity but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:761)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
    ... 18 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path /charity but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:761)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```